# Path between nodes in a colored oriented tree with given weight sum

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Consider an oriented tree where each node is colored either black, white, or both. In addition, each (oriented) edge has a given weight.

I am trying to see whether there exists a pair $(u, v)$ of nodes such that both of them are black (also means that both of them can be B&W or one black and one B&W) AND

• there exists an oriented path from $u$ to $v$ such that the sum of weights on this path is equal to a given integer K.

• the sum of weights on the undirected path from $u$ to $v$ is equal to K (we are ignoring the orientation of the vertices here).

I don’t care about the vertices, I need just a YES/NO answer.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something.  In a tree there is only one path between $u$ and $v$ so I don't understand the distinction between the two bullet points.  If the first holds, how can the second fail?

Comment: I really considered it as 2 separate problems. Of course the first implies the second, but I would like to modify the searching algorithm for the second one rather than running the first one and see whether it fails or not.

Comment: It seems like you could have one algorithm, `findPath(T, K, directed)` where T is a tree and directed is either true or false.  Would that fit your requirements?

Comment: if it still would be optimal for the first one, then yes

Comment: Are the weights nonnegative?

Comment: yes, they are .